# ASP.NET MVC Como Manipular a Tabela Users Usando Code First

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6, code-first, fluent-api

Estou estudando MVC ASP.NET *code first*. Sou iniciante e estou com uma dúvida provavelmente básica. Ao iniciar um projeto, ele já cria uma aplicação básica, inclusive com a tabela **User**. Acontece que estou querendo fazer um relacionamento entre esta tabela User com outra que eu criarei, por exemplo **Comments**. Então ficam duas perguntas:

a) Pra fazer o relacionamento no code first, eu preciso dizer que a tabela **User** tem uma lista virtual de Comments. Como fazer isso se não vejo o model de **User**?

b) Como definir as regras dos campos pelo *Fluent API*, se não tenho o Model?

Obrigado!!

Comment: Você poderia postar os trechos de código relevantes da sua aplicação para eu poder avaliar melhor o problema?

Comment: Acho que não ficou claro. Não é ag=lgo que eu tenha desenvolvido. Eu estou querendo manipular a tabela que o ASP.NET MVC cria automaticamente. Ele já cria User, User_Roles, e mais algumas. Estas tabelas não foram criadas por mim, e sim pela própria aplicação. No momento que eu rodo a aplicação, ele já cria o banco de dados e estas tabelas. Ou seja, eu não criei a entidade Users.. Essa é a pergunta. Como manipular esta tabela pelo código, já que não possuo o modelo criado por mim.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olá, creio que o artigo **[ASP.NET Identity - Customizando cadastro de usuários](http://www.eduardopires.net.br/2014/03/asp-net-identity-customizando-cadastro-usuarios/)** no blog do Eduardo Píres, possa te ajudar.

Espero ter ajudad.

Comment: Era exatamente o que estava procurando. Super obrigado, Edney!!